# Will 5/4 decking span 26" for a dock?

Tags: wood

I'm building a fishing dock. Using 5/4x6 for decking and 2x10 supports. Will a 5/4x6 work with a 26" span between 2x10s?

Comment: 5/4x6 _what_? Details matter.

Comment: 2x10 is very heavy for a dock. Why not four 2x8s? If you care to share your design we may be able to save you some weight and expense.

Comment: Sketches help us understand exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I only use 2X for decking. I  don't like the "bounce" of walking on 5/4. Also 2X has longer life.

Comment: I'm using 2x10"s because I have about 20 left over from another project. I have 3 docks with 5/4 x 6 decking. No bounce at all. But they're 16" span.

Answer (score 1):

For normal deck purposes, 5/4 decking is recommended for joist spacing of 16" or less. 2x decking is recommended for spans of 24" or less.

I would imagine docks should at least follow deck standards, so I would not try either 5/4 or 2x with 26" spacing, I would say to decrease your spacing if possible.

Answer (score 0):

#### In theory:

The [Sagulator](https://woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/) says that a 5/4" x 6" western red cedar plank will span 26" with a *static* load of 250lbs with 0.002" deflection per foot (note that's 0.004" for your 24"+ span).
In theory, you should be OK.

#### However...

That is for a *static* load of *only* 250lbs and it's Western Red Cedar. Your choice of wood will matter. The amount of weight will matter. The fact that it'll be people moving around, not just stuff sitting on a shelf will matter. A ***lot***.

26" joist spacing is rather unusual. Often, roof joists/trusses are spaced 24" on center because the roof is pitched so that there is relatively little weight on them (though snow load is no small matter). Usually floor/deck joists are 16" or even 12" on center and would be more common.

Considering that this is a dock, over water, and falling through could lead to drowning, I would suggest being conservative in design, even though it would cost more. A couple hundred dollars spent on beefing up the deck design now is *far* cheaper than hospital bills for falling through, especially if it's falling through, hitting your head and drowning because you're unconscious.

You're probably OK to use the 5/4" decking (it's very commonly used for house decking), but I'd *strongly* recommend much closer joist spacing.'

Notes:

- I see you've specified that you're using 2x10s. The height of the joist (10" in this case) is determined by the distance it has to span and doesn't impact, one way or the other, the decking material on top of it.
- I'd suggest you may want to consider using 2x material for your decking.

  - I build a deck using 5/4 decking and it squeaks horribly when I walk on it.
  - The same year, my brother in law built a deck with 2x decking and his is solid as a rock with no squeaks at all.

### The final say...

...rests with your local building authority. This may not be in a city, but the county may want to have a say in it, and the local DNR may have a say about building a dock on whatever waterway you're building on, and may have some code enforcement authority, as well.

Answer (score 0):

For regular deck construction, the spacing is supposed to be 16" so I'd say no.  I have an area on my deck with a spacing of 26" dues to a hot tub and the boards "bounce" a bit. It's the removable piece over the motor and heater so it not walked upon unless a DIYer asks a question about spacing. :-)  I'd use 2 x 6's.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but **run sleepers between**. By tying adjacent deck boards together you'll spread the load, so though you'll have a bit of bounce it'll be strong enough. I'd use 2x4s on edge so you can use at least 2-1/2" screws.

Answer (score -1):

A 2x10’s maximum span at 24” on center is 11’5”, assuming it’s Southern Yellow Pine (SYP) (Western Red Cedar is 8’8”). Assuming you’re using PT SYP 5/4” boards, understand, for composite decking, which is much more flexible, joist spacing is 16”. That being said, some deck builders use 20” spacing for 5/4” boards but advise using larger joists, such as 2x10’s. The reason being is, of course, bounce. My advice is to use the 2x10’s but install blocks, also 2x10’s (another poster called them “sleepers”) every 24”. This prevents the joists from twisting and will almost prevent the bounce completely because it ties all the joists together (unless a 400# football player tries to tackle the guy who stole his fries). I’m pretty sure you don’t need to worry about falling through the deck, even at 26” spacing. Good luck.